# Side effects of not using row/column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to develop a pricing section of a site, which contains 3 different prices. At the very top there should be a header and a short description, something like "Pricing", "The pricing plans:

```
<section id="pricing">
  <div class="container">
     <h2>Pricing</h2>
     <p>The pricing plans</p>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now, I've seen people put things that are supposed to be 1-row/1-column, directly inside the container, as above. If I followed the Boostrap "convention", then I'd do:

```
<section id="pricing">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <h2>Pricing</h2>
              <p>Here are our pricing plans</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4"></div>
              <div class="col-md-4"></div>
              <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

But, isn't putting a row with single `col-xs-12` reduntant? If you see the [source of the Bootstrap home page](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/), you'll notice `<p>` tags directly inside the `container`. However, here, the `<h2>` and the `<p>` tags aren't the ONLY things inside the container, there is a row following them.

So my question is, will there be any un-intended side-effect of using the first example vs. "following the rules" and using the second examples?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap Grid framework relies on padding and margins for proper placement.  When you omit either the `.row` or `.col-*-*` you create alignment issues.  Consider the following code:

```css
.default {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
  
.no-column {
  background: gray;
}
    
.no-row {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 default">
      <p>A paragraph within a col-12 element</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <p class="no-column">A paragraph with no column wrapper.</p>
  </div>
  
  <p class="no-row">A paragraph with no column or row wrapper.</p>
</div>
```

In the first example we have a grid element that follows Bootstrap's framework; text is wrapped within a column that is wrapped within a row that is part of the `.container-fluid` element.

Everything aligns as expected.

In the second example we omit the column.  Immediately we lose the padding created by `.col-*-*` and your paragraph presses up against the extreme left margin of the container.

In the 3rd example we omit not only the column, but also the row class.  As you can see the spacing difference becomes even more extreme.